# R scanning a variable

Tags: r, variables

In R, is there a way to use the scan(n=1) and scan a variable?
I'll explain myself better;

```
x<-10
y<-scan(n=1)
```

I want to make the function y=2*x+3
while inputting the value of y, can't I put in input directly 2*x+3? Is there a way to achieve such a thing?

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you just mean `2*scan(n=1)+3`?

Comment: hum... no. The opposite. I have the value of x saved, and I wanted to get the equation in input without having to get all the coefficents.

Comment: What is being typed in by the user, and what is being computed without user input? If you want to input x and then compute y, it's `x=scan(n=1)` and `y=2*x+3`. If you don't want to input anything from the user, it's `x=10` and `y=2*x+3`.

Comment: Oh yeah, and if you want to input y and compute the x such that y=2x+3,  it's `y=scan(n=1)` and `x=(y-3)/2`.

Comment: Yeah but in that way the equation would be pre-determinated, while I wanted to be user-defined.

Comment: Ah so you want the user to type in "2*x+3" and then have it evaluated to 10 because the variable is 10?

Comment: Yeah, but I guess that isn't possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code to read in an expression into y and then evaluate it:

```
> x <- 10
> y <- scan(n=1, what=" ")
1: 2*x+3
Read 1 item
> result <- eval(parse(text=y))
> result
[1] 23
```